# Fix/Replace a Small Knockout

Tags: electrical, junction-box

In my latest home electrical adventure, I wanted to add another receptacle pulling power from a receptacle lower on the wall. All kinds of problems along the way (e.g., hot/neutral reverse). The current problem is that I popped out a knockout on the original box and find **arghh, the knockout is a little smaller than a standard 1/2" knockout**. Based on some other questions, it sounds like it may be for BX or other types of cable, but not NM. Which (finally) gets to the question:

If I pop out a smaller knockout (my guess is it is probably 1/8" too small for a standard *3/8" (1/2" knockout)* clamp), what I can do to fix the problem, short of replacing the box? In a quick search, it looks like the big box stores (easy to search online) don't have any smaller clamps. I am pretty sure I can't just leave that hole open. There are some other knockouts that appear to be the right (normal) size, but what can I do to fill the hole? I have the knockout circle, but obviously it won't stay in. Since a standard clamp can handle 2 cables (depending on size), it seems logical that there should be a smaller one that can handle one cable. But I can't find it.

Literally a $0.02 part, but not sure how to fix it.

I could just super-glue on a cover (e.g., a larger one) - would that be acceptable?

Comment: What about one of these guys: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTBZz.png? I'm not sure how small they go.

Comment: @gnicko That would work. But what is it? (I mean, the picture is nice but that doesn't tell me what I need to actually buy.)

Comment: Sorry. "Electrical box knock-out covers"? I'm not really an electrical guy, so they might be known as something else by those who are more knowledgeable... but (Google)[https://www.google.com/search?q=electrical+box+knock+out+seal] seems to pick up on the term...

Comment: @gnicko Well, now I know the term is "knockout seal". But the problem is the same companies are making them and selling them *in the same sizes as the clamps* - i.e., it looks like 1/2" (which is really much bigger than 1/2", to confuse things...) is the smallest size.

Comment: Wait, you actually found a *real* hot-neutral reverse, *in the wild*?   I thought those only existed as tester malfunctions lol...  Sounds like that is the custom slightly D-shaped opening for BX cables.  Well, you could always plug it with a few inches of BX...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica A few months ago in one of my earlier adventures I found two hot/neutral reverses in one circuit - so the second tested OK until I fixed the first one! (Both now have nice new grounded receptacles, wired correctly.)

Comment: Half this post should be edited out. The long detailed backstory is really not needed to answer the question.

Comment: If it's a hole that a 1/2" KO plug doesn't fit then it doesn't really matter IMO. Junction boxes have holes all over. Sounds like you're having a hard time getting it in, which is as per usual; those are a pita. Bend the clips in a little first. - If it's actually a 3/8 KO then get a 3/8 KO plug.... Still gonna be a pita.

Comment: Picture of a box with a 3/8 KO? Never seen that. It's 1/2" and up. The only thing in 3/8 is the ones that come with cable clamps for 3/8 FMC. All 3/8 connectors will say "for 1/2 KO"

Answer (score 3):

I found [this article in the Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/home/how-can-i-seal-the-open-knockouts-in-my-electrical-boxes/2022/01/02/fa1976de-67f0-11ec-b0a7-13dd3af4f70f_story.htmlhttps://) that might help you out:

> But as you have discovered, plugs labeled as being ¾ of an inch aren’t
> designed to cover holes that diameter. Instead, **the size listed on the
> packaging is the “trade size,” which means the diameter of the
> electrical conduit that would fit through the hole with a little extra
> wiggle room to make it easy and quick to fit the parts together.** A
> plug with a trade size of ¾ of an inch is designed to fill a hole
> 1.109 inches in diameter, or about ⅓ of an inch wider than what you need.
>
> The next smaller size, ½ inch, doesn’t work, either. It is designed to
> fill a hole 0.875 inches in diameter. **Plugs with a trade size of ⅜ of
> an inch come closest, but they are a bit too small, filling holes
> 0.718 inches in diameter. Plus, this size is hard to find, because most household wiring requires conduits of at least ½ inch.**
>
> Standard knockout plugs have crimped prongs on the back. The idea is
> to press or hammer a plug into place from outside the box. The prongs
> compress and press inward to fit through the hole, then spring back
> into place to keep the plug snug against the box and virtually
> impossible to remove. **It might be possible to use a ½ -inch plug and
> reach inside the box (with the power cut off at the circuit breaker)
> with a screwdriver to press the tabs outward enough to hold the plug
> in place.**

[3/8" Plugs](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-8-in-Metal-Hole-Plug-807768/204273766)

[1/4" Plugs](https://www.homedepot.com/p/1-4-inhttps://www.homedepot.com/p/1-4-in-Nickel-Plated-Steel-Hole-Plug-807748/204273764-Nickel-Plated-Steel-Hole-Plug-807748/204273764)

The article continues...

> But a less common type of plug, called a three-piece seal, might work
> without that fussing. This type of plug has a threaded strap on the
> back and a circular cap on the front, with a screw in the center that
> connects those two parts.

[3-piece, 1/2" cover](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-Seal-1-2-in-Knockout-3-Piece-4-Pack-20605/314822916)

> You loosen the screw but don’t remove it. Then you wiggle the strap
> through the opening. By pressing down, you can get the whole length of
> the strap through the hole. Then you raise the cap so it’s centered
> over the hole and tighten the screw, which pulls the inside and
> outside parts together for a tight seal. **The back of the strap is
> shaped so it automatically centers in the hole, although it is
> designed to do this for a standard trade-size opening. (If you buy ½
> -inch seals, the best fit for your situation, the cap probably won’t tighten exactly over the center of the hole.)** An off-center fit is
> fine, but shine a flashlight into the box. If light comes through a
> gap, somewhat loosen the screw and nudge the cap into a slightly
> different position. If you are working overhead, try removing the
> screw and reversing the direction. Then press the strap through from
> the inside of the box, and tighten the screw from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

> I could just super-glue on a cover (e.g., a larger one) - would that be acceptable?

Nothing suitable was in stock at my local Home Depot when I stopped in to get other stuff (like a shallower box because the wall isn't normal depth, and some 12/2 NM because it is a 20A circuit and I'd like to keep it 20A) and I had no time to stop anywhere else. So I went with the glue option since nobody (Harper?) objected, and in fact I found some other questions that had similar sorts of repairs.

A drop of super glue and a larger knockout is covering the hole just fine.

(And then I had all the other work because of all the other problems in the old box and the wall and...but all now done, with grounds to the boxes properly (unlike before), high quality self-grounding screw clamp receptacles (unlike the old one). Just one more piece to add to my drywall patch To Do list...)

Comment: It's better than the nothing I would've done. But I still don't believe you that it's not a 1/2" knockout. Swearing here is necessary : Those are a supper fucking pain in the ass *every fucking time*.

Comment: I don't know what the official name is, but it was definitely a knockout for something. I tossed it when I cleaned up, and none of the project pictures I took are close enough to see the hole in the box. I am definitely **not** opening things up again just to measure it. The terminology of *1/2"* is a bit confusing. By my measure on a new box, a standard knockout is maybe a drop under 7/8" in diameter. That fits a connector such as [this Halex20511](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Halex-3-8-in-Non-Metallic-NM-Twin-Screw-Cable-Clamp-Connectors-5-Pack-20511/100133208) which is sold as

Comment: *3/8" (1/2" KO)*. The knockout I removed from the old box was just a little smaller - my guess is between 5/8" and 3/4". If I recall correctly, the old box had 4 knockouts like that - two top, two bottom, one of the bottom had a metal sheath cable - I am pretty sure BX - going through it into a clamp inside the box (which had the extra problem that the original installer had connected a ground wire for the receptacle to the clamp screw, so when I loosened the screw to remove the (a) incorrectly white and (b) unnecessary because I replaced with a self-grounding receptacle existing ground wire,

Comment: the cable came out unexpectedly). Plus it had one "normal" knockout in the back, which I used for the new NM cable (but I had to chip away at the brick behind the box because there was no room for the clamp & cable otherwise, which is why I had first picked a top knockout - to make life (ha ha ha) easier).

Comment: If it was a box with clamps in it, then maybe it did have some weird KOs that I've never seen, because for my codes it's EMT all day, and afaik that doesn't get any smaller than 1/2".

Comment: This box was most likely from the late 1950s or early 1960s. My guess is that this was a thing back in those days, as the knockout hole is large enough for BX to get through and then be held in an inside-the-box clamp. On the other hand, it could have been some wacky non-standard device, as so many things have turned out to be in the "homeowner improved" parts of the house.